# How to populate a dropdown with database entries in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I'm fairly new to rails and I'm building my first app. I've searched the web for a correct answer but couldn't find any that worked for my case.

I'm using simple form, with rails 4 and bootstrap 3. I have a `:location` dropdown on a (@employees) model and I want to populate it with a job_title column from my @positions model. I've used a scaffold to generate my position MVC + job_title:string job_description:string.

How can I populate my `:location` dropdown (on my employees form) with values from `:job_title` (from @positions model)? I currently have my code as:

```
<div class="col-md-6 pad-10"> 
<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(@positions, 'id', 'job_title') %>
<%= f.select :location, options, :input_html => { class: "form-control" } %>
</div>
```

But as you know, that doesn't work. Any help is appreciated!

> Solution:

```
<div class="col-md-6 pad-10"> 
<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(Position.all, 'id', 'job_title') %>
<%= f.select :location, options, :input_html => { class: "form-control" } %>
</div>
```

I used `Position.all` instead of `@positions`.

Comment: I get this error: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I think `options_from_collection_for_select` needs an Array. So try using `Modelname.all` instead of `@positions` or re-declare `@positions` with `@positions = Modelname.all`

Comment: It worked. I just used Position.all instead of @positions. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! please remember to tick the answer correct below :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options_from_collection_for_select` needs an Array. [Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

So try using `Modelname.all` instead of `@positions` or re-declare `@positions` with `@positions = Modelname.all`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using simple_form, you can render a select box for a collection like this:

```
<%= f.input :location, collection: @positions, label_method: :job_title, value_method: :id, input_html: { class: "form-control" }  %>
```

Comment: It renders a input box. If I change to f.select, it renders a dropdown, but the selections are label_method, value_method and colection. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure why it renders an input. This is documented on simple_form documentation https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form, please scroll down to collections part. Also, you may try passing as: :select to the f.input helper.

Comment: I read that too. So weird. Can't see to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Your answer worked as well by replacing the @positions for Position.all. But yours was better, because I was able to style the input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you if you want the `id` ofan `Position` object be written to the `location` field. If you want the `job_title` cahnge `:id` to `:job_title`.

```
<div class="col-md-6 pad-10"> 
<%= f.label :location %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :location, @positions, :id, :job_title %>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't work. I get a undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Your answer worked as well, just replaced the @positions to Position.all Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used `Position.all` instead of `@positions`.

```
<div class="col-md-6 pad-10"> 
<% options = options_from_collection_for_select(Position.all, 'id', 'job_title') %>
<%= f.select :location, options, :input_html => { class: "form-control" } %>
</div>
```